# Delete buffer only when a specific buffer is deleted

Tags: vimrc, neovim, buffers

I've configured Vim to look like this:

```
+------------------------------------+
| N  |              Code             |
| E  |                               |
| R  |                               |
| D  |                               |
| T  |                               |
| r  |-------------------------------|
| e  |              REPL             |
| e  |                               |
+------------------------------------+
```

Every element is in it's own buffer. Is it possible to delete the REPL buffer only when I quit the code buffer? If I open and close help, for example, the REPL should stay but when I close the code buffer, the REPL buffer should close as well.
This is what I have now:

```
let s:code_repl_nrs = {} " A map of (code buffer number) - (REPL buffer number)
let s:last_leaved_buffer_nr = -1 " The number of the last leaved buffer

autocmd BufLeave,BufDelete * let s:last_leaved_buffer_nr = bufnr('%')
autocmd BufUnload * call <SID>StopREPL(s:last_leaved_buffer_nr) " Stop the REPL when closing the code buffer

"" Stops a REPL given the number of the current buffer
function! s:StopREPL(buffer_nr)
    let l:repl_nr = get(s:code_repl_nrs, a:buffer_nr . '', -1) " Get the number of the REPL buffer
    if l:repl_nr != -1
        exec l:repl_nr . 'bdelete!'
    endif
endfunction
```

When I use `:h`, the REPL closes. How can I prevent this?

Comment: First you need to define the mapping according to some rule. For example, `:repl` command record the current buffer number and then maps it to the number of REPL buffer to be created then. And then is what you have written above that handle the BufDelete event. So what is your problem now?

Comment: The problem is that the REPL closes when I open help. I want to "link" the buffers - when one is closed, the other to be closed as well.

Comment: You call `StopREPL` on *all* `BufUnload` events… that includes the help buffer closing, no?

Comment: What do you mean by "_all_"? Isn't the `*` enough for all `BufUnload` events? Also the REPL closes when the help buffer opens for some reason. I tried to examine that behavior by making a bunch of autocmds which echoed a message but I couldn't understand which buffer is unloaded.